# how to use a user defined types in other class, which is defined in some class?

Tags: c++

just guess we have class like

```
class A{
public:
struct B{
...
};
typedef B C;
};
```

then, I'd like to use the C type in other class, that is other cpp.

how to use it?

Thanks

Comment: `A::C` I guess.

Comment: Include the `.h` file, and then `A::C`.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare a class, then in the class declaration you are in the namespace of the class. Let's have a look at a simple class:

```
class Sample{
public:
    void doSomething();
};
```

And let's say we also have a namespace:

```
namespace sampleNamespace{
    void doAnotherThing();
}
```

If you want let's say a pointer for both of those functions you would say:

```
auto* ptrFunction = Sample::doSomething;
auto* ptrAnotherFunction = sampleNamespace::doAnotherThing;
```

So the syntax itself is the same. Now let's take your example into account:

```
class Sample{
public:
   struct A{};
   typedef B A;
};
```

and let's convert it to the namespace conventions:

```
namespace Sample{
   struct A{};
   typedef B A;
}
```

Now if you want to use struct A you can do both (but members must be publicly visible):

```
//first option
Sample::A variableName;

//second option
Sample::B variableName;
```

Although you cannot of course use using namespace to achieve this :)
So in general in cases like this you can think of classes like of namespaces.

Comment: `Sample::doAnotherThing;` should be `sampleNamespace::doAnotherThing;`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just include the `.h` i.e `header` file and use A::C. For e.g

#### Header.h

```
class Demo {
  public:
    struct A {
      int data;
    };
    typedef A B;
};
```

#### Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h" // This is important

int main() {
  Demo::B *v = new Demo::B;
  v->data = 5;

  // This will print "The data is: 5"
  cout << "The data is: " << v->data << endl;
  delete(v);
  return 0;
}
```